# How do I interpolate $key$s in a file without applying a template?

Tags: hakyll

In Jekyll it is possible to have a file that looks like

```
---
title: Whatever
layout: null
---

<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

The `{{ title }}` will be interpolated, but the `layout: null` means that the file contents won’t be wrapped in any kind of template.

What is the equivalent in Hakyll? In other words, if I have a self-contained file like

```
<h1>$title$</h1>
```

what kind of block do I need to pass to `compile` in order to have the `$title$` value interpolated, *without* wrapping the page’s contents in some template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (thanks to erasmas in the #hakyll channel!) is to compile your page using

```haskell
getResourceBody >>= applyAsTemplate theContext
```

where `theContext` is the instance of `Context String` that contains the fields you want.

Here’s a toy example of how you’d use this compiler:

```haskell
main :: IO ()
main = hakyll $ do
    match "index.html" $ do
        route idRoute
        compile $ getResourceBody >>= applyAsTemplate indexContext

indexContext :: Context String
indexContext = mconcat
    [ constField "title" "My Website"
    , defaultContext
    ]
```